# Add selected number of text boxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add text boxes to my div. The number of text boxes is give by selection list.

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html>    
 <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>

 <body>     
  <div id = "text">
    Choose No.of TextBoxes:
    <select id = "options">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: And what is your question? What problem do you have? Here is a list of jQuery's DOM manipulation methods, which you can use: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/. How to work with event handlers is explained in the tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/events/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#options").change(function()
    {
        //Find if there is already a input box
        //if yes then remove it
        $("#text").find("input").remove();
        var count = $(this).val();

        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            var ipBoxName ="myInput"+i;
            var ipBox = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="'+ipBoxName+'" />';
            $('div#text').append(ipBox);

        }  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/qSThs/2/)**

```
$('select#options').change(function () {
    $('div#text input').remove();
    var val = $(this).val();
    for (var x = 0; x < val; x++) {
        var createInputTextBox = '<input type="textbox" />';
        $('div#text').append(createInputTextBox);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("select").change(function () {
  $(this).siblings("input").remove();
  for (i = 0; i < this.value; i++) {
    $("<input/>", {
        type: text,
        id: "textbox" + i
        //you add more attributes here if you want
    }).appendTo("#text");
  }
});
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bPdPE/5/

Please look at [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) at jquery site.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in `jQuery` :-

```
 $('#options').change(function()
    {
        var no_of_textbox = $(this).val();   

        for(var i = 1 ;i<=no_of_textbox;i++)
        {
            $('#divtable').append('<input type="textbox" name="textbox"+i>');

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a function onchange events of your select box.
Like this

```
<select id = "options" onchange="setbox(this.value)">
```

Use it inside head tag.

```
<script>
function setbox(val)
{ 
     for(var i = 1 ;i<=val;i++)
     {
        $('#divtable').append('<input type="textbox" name="textbox">');

    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! Stop the `onchange`!! http://christianheilmann.com/2008/07/10/stop-using-onchange-select-boxes/