# display textbox as per the value selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select>
<option value="1"> 1 </option>
<option value="2"> 2 </option>
<option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Hi everyone :)

I have a page with drop down list and text box.The drop down list contains numbers.. once the user select value from drop down list it will display text boxes based on the chosen number...

I don't know how to perform this function :(

I need help ..

If 1 is selected from dropdown 1 text box should be displayed , if 2 is selected from dropdown 2 text box should be displayed...same as for remaining...

Thankyou..

Comment: have you tried any thing

Comment: the question does not seem complete, what is the logic to display text box. Can you use jquery?

Comment: @user2480797 Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997401/add-selected-number-of-text-boxes-using-jquery/16997997#16997997

Comment: no i have not tried anything .. use javascript to complete it..

Comment: can anyone tell me the code in java script for my above question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#slct').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val(); var toAppend = '';
            if (value == 1) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >"; $("#container").html(toAppend); return;
            }
            if (value == 2) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >"; $("#container").html(toAppend); return;
            }
            if (value = 3) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >"; $("#container").html(toAppend); return;

            }

        });

    });
     </script>
  </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
     <select id="slct">
   <option value="1"> 1 </option>
     <option value="2"> 2 </option>
   <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    </select>
   <div id="container"></div>
</div>
</form>
  </body>
   </html>
```

if jquery didn't work to you try this code :

```
 function change() {
        var select = document.getElementById("slct");
        var divv = document.getElementById("container");
        var value = select.value;
        if (value == 1) {
            toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >"; divv.innerHTML=toAppend; return;
            }
            if (value == 2) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >";divv.innerHTML = toAppend;  return;
            }
            if (value = 3) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >";divv.innerHTML = toAppend;  return;

            }
     }

<select id="slct" onchange="change();">
 <option value="1"> 1 </option>
<option value="2"> 2 </option>
 <option value="3"> 3 </option>
  </select>
  <div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: when i select 2 from dropdown i need two text boxes to be displayed..your code is not working sora..

Comment: did u correct your selectbox and add <option value="1" > u have to correct and add values to your options or it will not work this is a working example because i tried it myself

Comment: i just copied and pasted your code...its not working for me..the code u gave should be placed in body section rite ?

Comment: did u add jquery library in the head section of your code ? you can see a wroking example here : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/nErLP/1/

Comment: can u do one help.. can u post the full section of this code from top to bottom...

Comment: this working example also not working..when i select value from dropdown no text boxes are displayed...please help me..

Comment: you sure added the jquery library ?

Comment: above edited code is also not working.. i'm just running this code in web browser ... its not working

Comment: can u just make me clear why its not working for me.. or give a code in java script..

Comment: did this line:<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> instead of <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and it should work fine for u if not please post your full code

Comment: you need to add the jquery js library. As @Sora mentioned above.

Comment: how to add it ... what are the steps to add js library.. help me

Comment: @Sora, can you please approved my changes. I have added it properly. script end tag was missed and also http:.

Comment: this is not working.. i have tried the above code  in all ways.. can u give me java script instead of jquery

Comment: getting warning messages at these lines //<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">//

Comment: you can delete the runat='server' i am sorry i tried it on visual stuio and it add automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#slct').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val(); var toAppend = '';
            if (value == 1) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >"; $("#container").html(toAppend); return;
            }
            if (value == 2) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >"; $("#container").html(toAppend); return;
            }
            if (value = 3) {
                toAppend = "<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >&nbsp;<input type='textbox' >"; $("#container").html(toAppend); return;

            }

        });

    });
     </script>
  </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
     <select id="slct">
   <option value="1"> 1 </option>
     <option value="2"> 2 </option>
   <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    </select>
   <div id="container"></div>
</div>
</form>
  </body>
   </html>
```