# Grabbing the input value and display that as a value in another text box

Tags: html

Sorry, the title may be a bit confusing. The user is prompted to select a value from a drop-down menu. I want to be able to grab that value and display it in a different text box.

Below is where the user selects from a dropdown. How do I then create another text box that can display this value?

```
<div class="leftCol">
    Select the number:
</div>
<div class="rightCol">
    <select name="Account" value="ACCT_VALUE_KEY">
        <option disabled selected value> </option>
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display textbox as per the value selected from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080217/display-textbox-as-per-the-value-selected-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to update the value to text field.
You can get value and update the value by using the property `id`

```js
function update(){
  sel = document.getElementById("account");
  display = document.getElementById("display");
  
  display.value = sel.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftCol">
    Select the number:
</div>
<div class="rightCol">
    <select name="Account" id='account' onchange="update()" value="ACCT_VALUE_KEY">
        <option disabled selected value> </option>
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>Selected: <input type='text' id='display' /></div>
```

Comment: Very odd...looks like it should work but when I select the values, nothing appears in the Selected: text box

Comment: AH! Figured it out...was calling the wrong Javascript for some reason...